# ruby simple substitutions

Tags: ruby

very new to Ruby, I've got the following situation. I have a file with values separated by new lines, they look like this:

```
18917
18927
18929
...
```

I want to prepend a folder path to all of them, then grab the first 2 characters and prepend that as well, then the value in the file and then append a '.jpg' at the end so they would end up looking like this:

path/to/foler/18/18917.jpg

So I've code this ruby code:

```
folder = "/path/to/folder" 
lines = File.readlines("values.csv")
images = lines.collect.to_s.gsub("\n", ".jpg,") 
images.split(',').collect { |dogtag |  puts "bad dog: #{folder}/#{dogtag[0,2]}/#{dogtag}" }
```

Now, this almost works, the part that is not working is the grabbing of the first 2 characters. I also tried it with the method outside quotes (and without the #{} of course) but it just produces an empty result.

Could someone please point out my folly?

Eventually I want to delete those images but I'm guessing that substituting 'File.delete' for 'puts' above would do the trick?

As usual, thanks in advance for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: Are you sure `images = lines.collect.to_s.gsub("\n", ".jpg,")` is correct?

Comment: I tried this code. It works as you would expect it to work. The first two characters of the string are being returned                               jruby-1.6.2 :007 > images.split(',').collect { |dogtag |  "#{folder}/#{dogtag[0,2]}/#{dogtag}" }
 => ["foo/18/18917.jpg", "foo/18/18927.jpg", "foo/18/18929.jpg"]

Comment: @Tass: yes. I mean it works, that's about as sure I am of anything in Ruby :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't seem to be understanding what `collect` does.

I would rewrite your snippet like this:

```
File.read("values.csv").each do |line|
  puts "bad dog: /path/to/folder/#{line[0,2]}/#{line.chomp}.jpg"
end
```

-- Update for last comment: --

If you don't want to use an if statement to check if a file exists before deleting it, you have two option (AFAIK).

Use `rescue`:

```
File.read("values.csv").each do |line|
  begin
    File.delete "/path/to/folder/#{line[0,2]}/#{line.chomp}.jpg"
  rescue Errno::ENOENT
    next
  end
end
```

Or extend the `File` class with a `delete_if_exists` method. You can just put this at the top of your script:

```
class File
  def self.delete_if_exists(f)
    if exists?(f)
      delete(f)
    end
  end
end
```

With this, you can do:

```
File.read("values.csv").each do |line|
  File.delete_if_exists "/path/to/folder/#{line[0,2]}/#{line.chomp}.jpg"
end
```

Comment: I'm really new to ruby so I'm going by the methods that I've seen, hence my ugly code. This code you gave me almost works, but outputs '.jpg' in a new line because of the existing \n after every item.
`bad dog: /path/to/folder/30/30427
.jpg`
So I would need something to remove the newline character (that's why I had gsub before). 
I added this `line = line.gsub("\n", ".jpg")` above the puts and that did the trick. 
Thanks!

Comment: @kakubei: Oh yeah, sorry. Let me fix that... Ah I see you fixed it by using `gsub`, you could also consider `chomp`. See my revised answer.

Comment: Never heard of chomp, I'm assuming it simply gets rid of the \n?
Thanks again. I really like Ruby, it's a wonderful language but I'm very new to it. Oohh, tried chomp and it worked great. Once more, thanks.

Comment: @kakubei: yes. You can learn a lot from the Ruby API. E.g. have a look at the reference for [`String#chomp`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/chomp).

Comment: If I could press my luck here, I now need to check that the file actually exists before trying to delete it or I get an error. I'd like to do it without a second if construction. I tried to use File.exist? but it does't seem to take.

Comment: One of the nice (and confusing) things about ruby is that you can chain methods together. So I thought I could do something like File.exist?.delete(filename) but that throws an error.

Comment: Chaining does not work in this case because `exists?` returns a boolean and a boolean does not have a `delete` method. I added two suggestion to my answer for deleting files without adding an if statement to the iteration.

Comment: Thanks I will try rescue. Any reason why this wouldn't work?
`if File.exist?("#{folder}/#{line[0,2]}/#{line}")
    File.delete("#{folder}/#{line[0,2]}/#{line}")
end`
(sorry can't get newlines in these comments, this code is really hard to read without them).

Comment: That would work, but I thought you were asking how to avoid using an if statement... rereading your comment it says "second if construction". I don't know what you mean by that..?

Comment: Yes I did, I'm just trying to learn. Rescue did the trick nicely, thanks.